# Which quadrant does -1.326 rad go?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

Which quadrant does -1.326 rad go? Please tell me how to find out by using the unit circle. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The unit circle consists of $2\pi \approx 6.3$ radians. Thus, noting that

$$\frac{-\pi}{2} < -1.326 < 0$$

this angle lies in between the angles $-\pi/2$ and $0$, in the fourth quadrant.

Answer (score 1):

If we rotate the point $(1,0)$, with $(0,0)$ as the centre of rotation, through an angle of $\theta$ radians then the point will be at $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$. In your case $\theta =-1.326$, where the minus sign denotes a clockwise rotation instead of the anti-clockwise rotation given by a positive $\theta$. In your case

$$(\cos\theta,\sin\theta) \approx (0.24,-0.97)$$

The quadrant with positive $x$-coordinates and negative $y$-coordinates is the fourth quadrant.

Notice, also, that since $2\pi$ is a full turn, $-1.326$ is $-1.326\div 2\pi$, about $-0.21$, of a full turn, i.e. less than one quarter of a clockwise turn. This tells you that you are also in the fourth quadrant, i.e. t the right of the $y$-axis and below the $x$-axis.